# JVM Failover Issue

Tags: java, jvm

I have an issue with this code. I have 2 servers running a JVM concurrently, serverA and serverB. Apart from the name, all the processes, software are identical. The idea is that if the JVM on the serverA fails, the JVM on serverB will take over immediately.

For checking which server is the main, I run a checking method which updates a table (server name and update date) in the database.

For example, while serverA is main, it will check if the current server in the DB is serverA. If so,  it will update the server name and last update timing on database. If not (main = ServerB), it will check the difference between the current time and last update timing. If the result is >50 secs (suggesting an issue with the current main server), serverA will update itself as the main.

The issue I am facing is that there have been instances where both servers are updating itself as main. For example:

ServerA updated around 6:20:23

ServerB updated around 6:20:59

Due to these two trying to both run the JVM processes at the same time, I have instances where both JVM's create a lock on the same job. Normally when these issues happen, the JVM of the non-main server will hang and eventually get a Out-of-Memory error.

I would like to know if there are any ways to stop one server (restart the JVM?) when the other takes over, or to prevent the 2 servers from fighting for the main position.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if (WmsParam.HOST_SERVER_NAME.equals(r.getLastUpdatePname())) //check if current server is still main
    {
        result = true;
    }
else
    {
        Calendar nowTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        long lastUsed = r.getLastUpdateDate().getTime();
        long nowTimeMili = nowTime.getTimeInMillis();

        long diff = nowTimeMili - lastUsed;

        long diffSec = diff /1000;

        if (diffSec >= WmsParam.HOST_DELAY_SECONDS) //host_delay_seconds = 50
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }

if (result)
        {

            rsAkey.setKey(rsKey);
            rsAkey.updateLastUsedDate(new Date());
            rsAkey.updateLastUpdatePname(WmsParam.HOST_SERVER_NAME);

            reasonHandler.modify(rsAkey);
            getConnection().commit();

        }
```

Comment: This is a hard problem. Any reason you are not using a database built for this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of your question. The JVM is running multiple processes for operations, and the database table is to tell us which one is the main.